# gdb won't open a compiled python in Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: python, linux, macos, gdb

I can't open my compiled `Python` file in my Mac OS X 10.10 in `gdb`.

I tried these two options to open the file but it still not work:

```
p0sxs-iMac:~ p0sx$ gdb --args /usr/bin/python
```

Giving the error:

> Error message from gdb: not in executable format: File format not recognized

Second option:

```
gdb --args python ./ReaFile.py
```

Giving the error:

> Error message from gdb : not in executable format: File format not recognized

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like gdb is not capable of running a Universal binary. See post:

- https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2011-11/msg00133.html

> > > file /usr/bin/python
> > >       /usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
> > >       /usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):      Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
> > >       /usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):        Mach-O executable i386
> >
> > Is there a way to build gdb to work around this?
>
> No.  Currently gdb is not able to debug fat binary.  Use lipo to
>   extract the architecture you want to use.